# Typo3 own repository for pages is not using the correct database table (pages)

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

We like to create a model and repository for querying the typo3 pages table.

Therefore we create a model (Dealer) and a repository (DealerRepository). We added the mapping to the pages table with TS setup

`config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.Tobias\CarApi\Domain\Model\Dealer.mapping.tableName = pages`

The setting is loaded. I can see it in the TS Browser.

Unfortunately a findAll() respond with a error, that the table (auto-generated) doesn't exists:

`Internal Server Error: Table 'typo3.tx_carapi_domain_model_dealer' doesn't exist`

In the db table `cf_extbase_datamapfactory_datamap` is also the wrong table. When I change the entry `tableName` there to `pages` it works perfectly.

I did everything like many sources describes and cleared the caches and db entries, so does have anyone an idea what we are missing?

Typo3: 8.7.9

Comment: TYPO3 version? I guess 8

Comment: Typo Version 8.7.9

Comment: Did you clear the Cache via Install Tool?

Comment: Is it a frontend plugin or backend module?

Comment: @Wolfgang: Yes, we cleared it.

It's in Restler, which is nothing really but most likely the frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always add such essential TypoScript settings to a file `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` in my extension and insert the settings there:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    Tobias\CarApi\Domain\Model\Dealer {
        mapping {
            tableName = pages
        }
    }
}
# for backend and cli API
module.tx_carapi {
    persistence.classes {
        Tobias\CarApi\Domain\Model\Dealer < config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.Tobias\CarApi\Domain\Model\Dealer
    }
}
```

This will always be loaded in any circumstances.